# Obj C - NSUserDefaults won't give back values to calculate, after loading the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I am stuck with little problem. I have basic calculating app.

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    self.currentSettings = _currentSettings;
    [self calculateThePrice];
}

-(void)calculateThePrice
{
    float wynik = self.currentSettings.kwh * self.currentSettings.price;
    self.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f %@", wynik , self.currentSettings.currency];
}
```

SettingsVC.m

```
#import "SettingsVC.h"
@interface SettingsVC () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end

@implementation SettingsVC
#pragma mark - UserDefaults Implementation

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self createCurrencyArray];

    NSUserDefaults *priceDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *priceDefText = [priceDef stringForKey:@"priceCall"];

    _priceTextField.text = priceDefText;   

    NSUserDefaults *currencyDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [_currencyPicker selectRow:[currencyDef integerForKey:@"currencyCall"]
         inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    [priceDef synchronize];
    [currencyDef synchronize];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *textOfPriceTexField = _priceTextField.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textOfPriceTexField forKey:@"priceCall"];
}
```

Now, the problem is when I want program to automatically-calculate, it won't. To have any result, I have to switch to Second View, choose a value from picker and then when I will go back, I have my result.
But...
 - When I change value on 1st screen, result won't change. When I change value on 2nd scree, result won't change. But when I change value on PickerView - TADAH - result updates!

- When I go to second view, and go back to first, then go again to second and go back to first, my result changes to "0.00 (NULL)"...

Any ideas where I did wrong? I think it is about NSUserDefaults, I tried many options, nothing worked, nor changed anything.

Comment: float wynik -> using regional language is always really bad practice. BTW: Witamy ;). You can also call `[NSUserDefaults synchronize]'` to immediately save to `NSUserDefaults`. `UserDefaults` pragma mark is in wrong place, as you have viewWillAppear etc method - this is view lifecycle. You should separate methods for nsuserdefaults, call them, and show us only that call, rest of code you're posting is long to read. Your code is only updating on viewDidAppear and you expect it to work all the time. You shuld call that function to reload data after an action (eg clicking `=` button on keyboard).

Comment: Thank You for pointing me out that I posted too much code - i thought that It will be better if I paste anything that is connected with those methods.

Comment: first clean your code: 1. You do not need to send `synchronize` to `NSUserDefaults`.  1.1. It is done by the system. 1.2. You do not change the content. 2. `priceDef` and `currencyDef` refers to the same unique user defaults database. Get the reference one time. 3. Use formatters. (This is unrelated to your problem.)

Comment: Check, whether `-textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called. (Setting a break point or logging a message.) If it is not, is the delegate reference set?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad - 1. deleted syncrhonize, 2. changed to "def", 3. in future
`-textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called, yes. Could You explain this "delegate reference"?
I have this 
`@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Comment: If it is called, everything is fine at this location. But what do you mean with "in future"?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, i misunderstood what did you mean by "Formatters", therefore I did not think where should I use them. Here on SOverflow or in code?

Comment: You should use it in your code. :-) And of course, after changing your code you should repost it here. This applies to synchronize, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize NSUserDefaults when you set new values. You are using synchronize when you retrieve values.

Here you don't need 2 pointers to defaults and don't need synchronize:

```
NSUserDefaults *priceDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *priceDefText = [priceDef stringForKey:@"priceCall"];

_priceTextField.text = priceDefText;   

[_currencyPicker selectRow:[priceDef integerForKey:@"currencyCall"] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

Here you need synchronizes:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{

    NSString *textOfPriceTexField = _priceTextField.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:textOfPriceTexField forKey:@"priceCall"];
    [defaults synchronize]; 
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [_currencyPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:selectedRow forKey:@"currencyCall"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    self.currentSettings.currency = [self.currencyArray objectAtIndex:row];
    self.currentSettings.price = [self.priceTextField.text floatValue];

    //[self userDidFinishSetting];
}
```

Comment: Why down vote [?]
Unfortunately, your soultion did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSString *textOfPriceTexField = _priceTextField.text;
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textOfPriceTexField forKey:@"priceCall"];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self createCurrencyArray];  
    NSUserDefaults *priceDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *priceDefText = [priceDef objectForKey:@"priceCall"];
}
```

instead of stringForKey you can call objectForKey same as for integerForKey also you can call objectForKey. Actually you are setting the object not string or integer.

Comment: Hm, I dont think that can be a root of problem, because TextFields saves in NSUserDefaults just properly! Problem is with UIPickerView, on viewWillAppear/Dissaper it has value = null.